# Usage of PropTypes in React js

Tags: reactjs, react-props

i'm trying to pass data from a parent component to a child component via "props"

to do so, i've defined:

```
<Sidebar name="Dave" />
```

in the parent component.

and the following in the state :

```
message: this.props.name,
```

in the child component.

now i'm getting:
[the error that i'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDfin.jpg)

now, i understood that i need to use PropTypes, for validation.

next thing that i did is to define:

```
SideBar.PropTypes = {
name: PropTypes.string,
```

}

as far as i know, it should be enough to fix the error,
could anyone please help me to figure this out?

the code of my Child Component: sideBar.jsx:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

class Sidebar extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
}
state = {
    message: this.props.value,
}

render() {
    return <div>hello {this.state.message}</div>
}
}
export default Sidebar

Sidebar.PropTypes = {
name: PropTypes.string,
}
```

the code of my Parent Component: Homepage.jsx:

```
class Homepage extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
}

render() {
    return (
        <>
            <Sidebar name='Dave' />
        </>
    )
}
}

export default Homepage
```

Comment: You put message in proptypes, but value in the actual implementation.

Answer (score 1):

The prop you passed is 'name', but the prop you used in your child component is 'value', so I think you should change your state as such:

```
state = {
    message: this.props.name,
}
```